# position:relative set on editable dropdown is displaying over header of web page when scroll down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my Html code for setting header and editable drop down

```
<div class="header" style="position:fixed; width:100%;">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="continer1ForProjectContext">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><a>img style="margin-left:10%; margin-top:0.3%;" ></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group has-success" style="margin-left:30%;">
            <div class="select-editable" id="select2">
                <select ng-options="item.label for item countryValues track by item.id" ng-model="selectedCountry">
                    <input type="text" name="Country" value="select" ng-model="selectedProject.label" id="txtProject" required />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS which i used

```
#continer1ForProjectContext{
    background-color: #009530;
      color: #959696;
      height: 65px;
}



.select-editable { 
    background-color:white;
    width:120px;
    height:18px;
    position:absolute;
}

.select-editable select {
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   font-size:14px;
   border:solid #3c763d 1px;
   width:170px;
   margin:0;
   height:30px;
   border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; 
   position:absolute;
}

.select-editable input {
   bottom:0
   width:150px;
   padding:1px;
   font-size:12px;
   border:solid #3c763d 1px;
   border-bottom:none;
   height:29px;
   border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
   position:absolute;
}

.select-editable select:focus, .select-editable input:focus {
   outline:none;
}
```

I want the header to be fixed which is done but at the same time when i scroll down the page the editable combo box is visible over the header. what is the problem??? any help is appriciable!!!

Comment: Add a [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to your header

Comment: I'll create an answer with a little more information, which could be usefull if someone has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This 'problem' is caused because position: absolute; and position: fixed; take an element out of the document flow. To make sure your 'layers' of elements are in the correct order on the z-axis, you can use [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

A good read with a little more information is found [here](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/).